# Did FireDac SQLite change in Delphi 10.4?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

My Delphi project has never used the actual sqlite3.dll but rather uses the embedded library.

I recompiled the project with 10.4 and sent it to testers who are seeing this error:

> Exception EFDException in module
> ChessOpeningsWizardProfessional2016.exe at 007C6FDC.
> [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite]-314. Cannot load vendor library
> [sqlite3.dll or libdb_sql51.dll]. The specified module  could not
> be found
> Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and
> has x86 bitness.

It runs fine on my machine without any Dll.

Has something in FireDac changed regarding Sqlite3 in Delphi 10.4 Sydney?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it did change - please see:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4#FireDAC_SQLite_driver_offers_both_static_and_dynamic_linkage

> For SQLite, FireDAC adds the ability to choose static vs dynamic linkage of SQLite engine. To use the static linkage of SQLite engine it is required to add the unit "FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat" to the uses clause of one of the units of your project. Otherwise dynamical linkage will be chosen. There is a new property TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.EngineLinkage. When the value is slDefault or slStatic, then the "FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat" unit will be added at design-time to the unit hosting the component. If application defines the connection at run-time, then the "FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat" unit must be added manually.

Comment: I still have no idea how it runs on my machines without the DLL.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC) states that one must "modify the FireDAC.inc file:

define FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC for static linking. Note: You can find the FireDAC.inc file under C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\data\firedac." 

But I cannot find any FireDAC.inc file in any of the Embarcadero source.

Comment: That part of the doc is out of date